# How to access iCloud Documents files in an asynchronous manner

Tags: ios, icloud, icloud-documents

I am trying to add support for iCloud Documents in my existing app, but I am struggling  badly with how to do that.

Apple seems to prefer that you use the `UIDocument` class for that. But UIDocument does not give direct access to the file in the file system, it expects to maintain a copy of the contents of the file in an NSData object instead. That is simply not doable in my case. All my current code and half of the 3rd party libraries that I use, work directly with the file on the file system, not with NSData. Rewriting all that code is simply not doable.

When not using the UIDocument class, Apple expects you to use the [`NSFileCoordinator`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilecoordinator) to coordinate access to the file's contents. I am trying to do that with my code, but the methods on the NSFileCoordinator seem to expect that all reading and writing will be done in one synchronous sequence. All the methods of NSFileCoordinator take a block as argument, and expect all the reading/writing to be performed inside that block. When the block returns, you are not allowed to make any file access anymore, as far as I understand.

That is not doable in my case as well. Some of my code, and the 3rd party libraries, do the reading / writing in an asynchronous manner on background threads. I can identify the start and end of the period that the code needs access to the file contents, so if there was a separate `requireAccess` method, and separate `relinquishAccess` on the `NSFileCoordinator`, that would enable me to achieve the goal. But that does not seem to be the case.

It is unclear to me what the role of `NSFilePresenter` in this is. Some of the documentation, especially that of [`relinquishPresentedItemToReader()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilepresenter/1410743-relinquishpresenteditemtoreader) in NSFilePresenter seem to indicate that you can actually acquire / relinquish access separately:

> If you want to be notified when the reader has completed its task,
> pass your own block to the reader and use that block to reacquire the
> file or URL for your own uses.

But it does not explain anywhere how to "reacquire" the file.

So the concrete question: I need to do the following steps in an asynchronous manner:

1. acquire access to the file, and obtain a `file:` URL for the file on the local file system
2. do multiple, asynchronous,
   read/write operations on the file with normal file system
   operations on that `file:` URL
3. relinquish access to the file

Does anybody know whether it is possible to do this, and how to do step 1 and step 3 ?

Comment: Will you have multiple file writers? `NSFileCoordination` isn't mandatory. It is advisory. Use of `UIDocument` can simplify code that does care about multiple file writers (either on the current host or on other hosts access the same iCloud file). All you really MUST do on iOS is call `NSMetaDataQuery` in order to force iCloud sync. I found this [blog](https://khanlou.com/2019/03/file-coordination/) post useful (especially the comment from an Apple engineer at the end).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the blog. I already use a similar mechanism as the one outlined in the blog internally. But, yes, it is a publicly visible iCloud directory I am writing to/reading from, so there can definitely be multiple writers.